# When can an "insider" sell shares to the market?

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, law

If all the necessary information about the company at the moment is already disclosed to the public, are insiders allowed to immediately sell as much as they want? Is there a limit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no law preventing or limiting "insiders" from buying or selling shares, but officers, directors, and other key employees must report their trades to the SEC.  What constitutes *illegal* insider trading is when the trader has **material, nonpublic information about the security**.  This law applies not only to actual insiders, but to friends, family, or anyone who obtains the information. If an insider provides material information to someone who then trades based on that information, then *both* parties may be guilty of securities law violations.

That said, many companies have internal policies that prevent certain people from trading in order to *prevent* illegal trading, particularly around the disclosure of quarterly earnings statements and the disclosure of significant activities, as they can have a significant impact on stock prices.

Comment: if it is an "insider" as in >10% holder of the outstanding shares but not an employee/manager/ceo of the company, but rather for example an underwriter, generally what does that person have to disclose? does his position count toward the float?

Comment: Unless the information is provided inadvertantly. Please see SEC vs. Switzer. http://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/FSupp/590/756/2247092/

Comment: You might also mention 10b5-1 plans, where officers of a company commit to stock sales in advance to avoid issues of insider trading. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEC_Rule_10b5-1#Affirmative_legal_defense_for_planned_trades

Comment: At what point is something considered inside information? It seems likely that someone working in a company always knows some minor information that isn’t public, like some deal likely to happen or fall through, technical problems with whatever, etc.

Comment: It would be up to a court to decide if the information was material or not.

Comment: actually im not sure if its correct to say theres no "limit" for insiders to buy or sell. if they own >10% they cannot sell more than 1% every 3 months right..?